не работает команды на git
Пишу значит бота. Все работало на протяжении двух недель идеально. Сейчас же чтото странное. Ввел команду git status, и на этом все. Ничего не происходит, прождав 10 минут, ничего не получилось, отменил команду через Control+C, попробовал еще раз - все тоже самое. Подумал что может с директорией что-то не то. попробовал тоже самое с другим проектом - все равно ничего не выводит. Подумал может проблема в самом гите. Версия актуальна, проблема именно с работой с директориями как я понимаю.

"Ничего не происходит" - ¿так процесс git все-таки создается? ¿Папка расположена на реальном рабочем жестком диске (не на сетевом/облачном/поломанным)?

@user7860670 Да, папка на реальном рабочем жестком диске, быть точнее на ссд.

Попробуйте что-то типа TortoiseGit`

Попробуйте для начала git fsck

Git работает плохо именно с этим проектом или он на любом виснет?

@Den виснет вообще в любом проекте. Не выполняется даже команда git fsck

@Faraday что это?

@Mishcan, ну ёлки-палки, загуглите в интернете

@Mishcan, уже интереснее а только git виснет? другие команды выполняет нормально?

@Den сложно сказать, я даже не знаю как проверить. Ну точно знаю что pwd , ls -la выполняются корректно

@Den команды brew тоже вроде как работает, переустанавливал через него сам гит , обновлял сам brew

Нашел решение. Все таки хорошо погуглив, нашел способ эффективный на 100%.
Нужно переименовать папку .git, чтобы временно отключить Git - mv .git .git_backup
Затем создаете новую .git папку - git init
Дальше переносите файлы из .git_backup в новую .git папку, для этого нужно удалить текущую .git папку - rm -rf .git
Теперь просто переименуйте .git_backup в .git, чтобы вернуть его на место - mv .git_backup .git
Теперь проверяете через команду git status
Должно сработать! Мне помогло только это!

Как-то это странно. ¿Процессов гита старых не висит ли в фоне, блокируя доступ к папке? ¿Или антивирусного что-то?

@user7860670 не знаю, как проверить?

Откройте аналог Process Explorer.

попробуйте полностью удалить git(подчистить все файлы которые знаете, если они останутся) и переустановить его(звучит глупо, но вдруг поможет)

не работат. Переустановил через сайт, через графический интерфейс, через homebrew. Ничего не работает. по прежнему так же виснет

Судя из ответов на комментарии, вариантов почему это может быть остается не так много:

т.к. git виснет в любом проекте, то проблема скорее всего в нем! Попробуйте полностью его удалить и установить новый(не забывайте удалить файлы конфига)
вы не писали на какой платформе работаете, но могут быть проблемы с путем к
к .exe файлу, проверьте "параметры переменных среды"(хотя это очень маловероятно, т.к. выдавал бы ошибку, а не вис)
достаточно большая вероятность, что проблема может быть с консолью(хотя честно сказать я не знаю как её можно сломать, но допустим), попробуйте открыть аналоги, powershell или другую версию.


платформа мак. Я когда удалял гит , его не было, но при это на команду git --version отвечал как - git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154). Посмотрел путь, а это оказался /usr/bin/git, узнал что это системный какой то гит на маке, который удалять крайне не рекомендуется
